# Total Commander: Duplicate current path of the panel in the other panel

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, total-commander

I want to duplicate current path of the panel in the other panel with one shortcut. This is like swapping panels but instead of swapping I want to duplicate. In xplorer2 this is done with `Ctrl-I`.

How to do this in Total Commander?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>, depending on direction.

Answer (score 3):

Another answer:  Set the panel to the drive letter that the panel you want to copy is on.  In switching to the drive it will get the directory.  Note that this works even if you're already on the drive.

Comment: Could be a bug or a feature - depending on what you are trying (not) to do :D lovely.
Wonder if it's actually intentional or not.

Answer (score 3):

Either click Commands>Target=Source or add a button to the toolbar with the `cm_MatchSrc` command.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Is there an opposite src=target command for the toolbar?

Comment: There is no target=source command if that´s what you are asking. That would be achieved just by selecting the opposite panel before executing target=source. The alternative command that´s available is Source<->Target, which flips the panels.